# where does magento2 store extension files after compilation

Tags: magento2, compilation

I need to know where does magento2 store extension files after compilation as i am making changes in extension i need to always run commands, if i don't want to run commands for some time as we can make change for css in pub/static folder

Answer (score 0):

It's under `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Vendor` for core modules

and for local modules `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/YOUR_THEME_NAME`